# Why don't they use ints to define constants instead of using bit shift operators?

Tags: go

In the [go source code](https://golang.org/src/runtime/hashmap.go?h=map), the constant `bucketCnt` is 8. Why is defined in terms of right-shifting 3 times instead of just defining it as 8.
I understand that `1 << x` implies `2^x`.

But, my question is...

Is

```
// Maximum number of key/value pairs a bucket can hold.
bucketCntBits = 3
bucketCnt     = 1 << bucketCntBits
```

better than

```
// Maximum number of key/value pairs a bucket can hold.
bucketCnt     = 8
```

Comment: Assuming `bucketCntBits` and `bucketCnt` have to match, yes, it’s better to set `bucketCnt` based on `bucketCntBits` than to rely on their separately-assigned values matching.

Comment: it seems like bucketCnt is supposed to be a multiple of 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> const (
>   // Maximum number of key/value pairs a bucket can hold.
>   bucketCntBits = 3
>   bucketCnt     = 1 << bucketCntBits
> )
> ```

The number of key/value pairs a bucket can hold depends on the number of bits used (`bucketCntBits = 3`). That translates to a bucket count (`bucketCnt`) of `1 << bucketCntBits` or 8. If we change the number of bits to 4 (`bucketCntBits = 4`) or 2 (`bucketCntBits` = 2) then `bucketCnt` is still `1 << bucketCntBits` or 16 or 4.

> ```
> // A map is just a hash table. The data is arranged
> // into an array of buckets. Each bucket contains up to
> // 8 key/value pairs. The low-order bits of the hash are
> // used to select a bucket. Each bucket contains a few
> // high-order bits of each hash to distinguish the entries
> // within a single bucket.
> ```

"The low-order bits of the hash are used to select a bucket."

References:

[src/runtime/hashmap.go](https://golang.org/src/runtime/hashmap.go?h=map)

[Go maps in action](https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action)

[GopherCon 2016: Keith Randall - Inside the Map Implementation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl7mi9QmLns)

[Macro View of Map Internals In Go (2013)](https://www.goinggo.net/2013/12/macro-view-of-map-internals-in-go.html)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why number of key/value pairs depends on the number of bits?

Comment: @cafed00d: See my revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using bit shift operators sets `bucketCnt` to be defined according to the value in `bucketCntBits`, so if `bucketCntBits` is changed, `bucketCnt` will change accordingly. Also, it more clearly expresses how `bucketCntBits` is related to `bucketCnt`.